# Can it be possible sending messages directly from lock screen in android or ios?

Tags: android, ios

I want to create an app for android and ios which can let users send messages directly from lock screen after giving the passcode for sure but without going to the homescreen and tapping the application. It would be faster probably.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact with your app from the lock screen is via enriched notifications. You can send a push notification and customize it to collect a certain text message from the notification extension. You can find more information about these notifications here [enriched notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications)